# how can I wrap zlib in golang?

Tags: go, zlib, cgo

I tried to fix the golang's slowest zip implementation by calling the c zlib from golang using cgo

but I get an error

error: 'deflateInit' undeclared (first use in this function)

deflateInit is defined in zlib.h

Am I missing something? thanks for any hints.

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "zlib.h"
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hmmm....")
    fmt.Println(int(C.random()))
    var strm C.struct_z_stream
    fmt.Println(strm)
    ret := C.deflateInit(&strm, 5) // trouble here
}
```

Comment: Please add: a) which command (full) you used for the above source b) where is the above source located wrt where is "zlib.h" located.

Comment: a) I just use go run cgotest.go 
b) the above source located in /Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/dawn/Documents/workspace/work/dev/sandbox/testgo/src/cgotest
c) zlib.h can be found on many places, I changed the include to 
    #include "/opt/local/include/zlib.h"
but still the same problem
Can you compile this on your computer ?

Comment: Tried for some time to no avail. Googling didn't helped neither :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code.  Note the `#cgo LDFLAGS: -lz` to link with the zlib library and the little C function `myDeflateInit` which deals with the fact that `deflateInit` is a macro rather than a function.  Note also the change in definition of `strm`.

C macros are rather irritating to deal with from Go unfortunately - I couldn't think of a better way than a small C shim function.

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lz
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "zlib.h"

int myDeflateInit(z_streamp s, int n) {
     return deflateInit(s, n);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hmmm....")
    fmt.Println(int(C.random()))
    var strm C.z_stream
    fmt.Println(strm)
    ret := C.myDeflateInit(&strm, 5)
    fmt.Println(ret)
}
```

Comment: oh, golang/cgo don't treat macro right, I get it! Thanks so much for the fixed version helps me so much!